# Does the defstruct instantiation evaluate its &key arguments?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to nest instances of defstructs as some of the &key arguments in another defstruct, as demonstrated by the code below. For some reason, the variables to be inserted into the outer defstruct are not being replaced with the values bound to them (which is what I would expect). Any explanations and/or suggestions would be appreciated.

```
(defstruct (compound (:conc-name nil)) op args)
(defstruct (var (:conc-name nil)) name)

(let* ((x (make-var :name 'x))
       (y (make-var :name 'y))
       (my (make-compound :op 'Mother :args y))
       (s1 (make-compound :op 'knows :args '(y my)))
       (s2 (make-compound :op 'knows :args '('John x))))
  s1)

=> #S(COMPOUND :OP KNOWS :ARGS (Y MY))
```

Comment: It may help to read a some more basic Lisp introduction book. Like Land of Lisp, or Touretzky's Gentle Introduction. Those explain the basic evaluation rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'(y my)` is a literal list that contains two symbols - `Y` and `MY`. `(list y my)` would create a list of two values, first is the value of variable `Y`, second is value of variable `MY`. The same is with '`('John x)` - it's a literal list that contains two elements - a list `(QUOTE JOHN)` and symbol `X`.

Comment: Ah! I was thinking that the '() and (list) notations were equivalent. Thanks for the clarification!